# Ignore filters in measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've this Measure in Power BI to calculate the average value ignoring low values (lower than the complete average previously calculated)

```
Measure = 
    var T1 =
        SUMMARIZE(RAD,RAD[deviceid],"SUMDEVICE",SUM(RAD[data]))
    VAR AVGDEVICE =
        AVERAGEX(T1,[SUMDEVICE])
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX(T1, IF([SUMDEVICE]>=AVGDEVICE,[SUMDEVICE]))/1000
```

In this page I have two slices, one to select a time range and other to select a device. In this case, for this measure I want to ignore the device filter from the slicer, only with the date filter.

The RAD table is simple, and it is something like this, I have 4 devices and data for all the days of the year:

| Date | DeviceId | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | 100 |
| 01/01/2022 | B | 120 |
| 01/01/2022 | C | 90 |
| 01/01/2022 | D | 74 |

I can't find how to ignore this filter and have a fixed value for the selected time range in the slicer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Measure = 
var T1 =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(RAD,RAD[deviceid],"SUMDEVICE",SUM(RAD[data]))
        ,ALL(RAD[deviceid]) -- works if the slicer is of this column or change to the proper tableName[columName] 
    )
VAR AVGDEVICE =
    AVERAGEX(T1,[SUMDEVICE])

RETURN
    AVERAGEX(
        FILTER(
            T1
            ,[SUMDEVICE]>=AVGDEVICE
        )
        ,[SUMDEVICE] 
    )/1000
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the slicer in another table column. I attach an image with the relationships model.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziFO8.png

What I'm using in the slicer is the T_C column from the table TC_MAP.
The relationship between PIRANOMETERS and TC_MAP is bidirectional because one piranometer(deviceId) have multiple T_Cs but T_Cs only have one piranometer(deviceId)

Any idea of how to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you try with `ALL(TC_MAP[T_C])` what is the result?

Comment: DAX has a function REMOVEFILTERS() it removes direct filter, but not crossfilter. This function is equal to ALL(). ALL() just shorter. When you use ALL() without argument it removes every filter in you data model.

Comment: Yes I tried ALL(TC_MAP[T_C]) and it doesnt work. I'm going crazy with this...

Comment: I've solutioned al last. I put SUMMARIZE(ALL(RAD).....

Comment: but didn't you remove a date filter as well? As I understood it should be active

Comment: Yes, I did SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(RAD,DateTable[Date])... too